# How to create simple login Rest API in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, rest

i am using Spring MVC and Hibernate to create login page where user can enter his name and password and click on
login button to get into his related page. I tried a lot to complete the login task but unfortunately didn't. Need help to complete this task .
Here is the code that i tried.

DAOInterface class

```
Admin loginAdmin(String name, String password);

DAOImplementation class
@Override
    public Admin loginAdmin(String name, String password) {
        Admin admin = (Admin) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createNativeQuery(name, password);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select name ,password from Admin where 
                                         name="+"'" + name +"'" +"and password=" + "'"+password+"'");   
        if(admin.getName() == name && admin.getPassword() == password){
            return admin;
        }else{
            return admin;
        }



    ServiceInterface class
        Admin loginAdmin(String name, String password);





ServiceImplementation class
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Admin loginAdmin(String name, String password) {
        return adminDao.loginAdmin(name, password);     
    }
```

Rest Controller class

```
    @GetMapping("login/{name}/{password}")
    private Admin loginAdmin(@PathVariable("name") String name, @PathVariable("password")String password){
        //boolean admin = 
        Admin admin= new Admin();
        admin = adminService.loginAdmin(name, password);
        if(name == admin.getName() && password == admin.getPassword()){
            System.out.println("Login successfull");
            return admin;   
        }else{
            System.out.println("user name and password is null");
            return admin;
        }
    }
```

Getting this Exception when call api from postmain

```
[Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown SqlResultSetMapping [coder]] with root cause
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown SqlResultSetMapping [coder]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.setResultSetMapping(NativeQueryImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNativeQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:907)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNativeQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:103)
    at com.LibraryManagment.spring.dao.AdminDAOImp.loginAdmin(AdminDAOImp.java:43)
    at com.LibraryManagment.spring.service.AdminServiceImpl.loginAdmin(AdminServiceImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy347.loginAdmin(Unknown Source)
    at com.LibraryManagment.spring.controller.AdminController.loginAdmin(AdminController.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

After completing this i will send request from Angular 8 which i used as front end

Comment: Why dont' get the hibernate Entity from the query? I guess is related to that way of doing the query.
Also avoid string append in queries, use proper placeholders, you risk a sql injection in this way.
Furthermore you can have a look at spring security to manage login, it should ease your work

Comment: You may want to consider Spring Security framework to manage authentication/authorisation features. How would you handle "admin" when other requests come? Apart from that the error above seems to be a no result query. Try to run your query direct against database.

Comment: @GuilhermeRibeiroDeveloper the reason behind this is i am new to spring and hibernate so i am trying to do this in a simple way .  yes i know that spring security will mange, and i run this query against database i am getting proper result.

Comment: @rascio the reason to ask question is that i am unable to write code for this if you help me out it will great to complete this task because i'm searching on google but did not get results.

Answer (score 0):

(The premise of this solution is that the `Admin` object is an hibernate entity)

To make your code works you should change your DAO class in something like:

```java
public Admin findByUsernameAndPassword(String name, String pass) {
     Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

     return (Admin) session.createQuery("FROM Admin WHERE name = :name AND password = :password")
            .setParameter("name", name)
            .setParameter("password", pass)
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

And in your service:

```java
public Admin login(String user, String pass) {
    return dao.findByUsernameAndPassword(user, pass);
}
```

In the controller then you have just to check if the `Admin` returned by t he service is null or not to know if the authentication was good.
(In your code you was comparing strings using `==`, you should use `.equals()` for them)

By the way as I suggested in the comment, I discourage this kind of approach as authentication (and authorization) can become pretty complex easily.

Being Spring a well used and tested framework spend some time studying its documentation is worth it, as it will avoid you to write lot of code when developing (so you are reducing the risk of accidental bugs).
If you are using SpringBoot then configure stuffs is very easy.

Here a list of guides that can help you with the development:

- Spring Security set up: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/
- Spring Security with DB users: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database
- Spring Security: https://spring.io/projects/spring-security#learn
- Spring Data JPA (very useful to work with hibernate): https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference